# What is status=24/XPU in syslog?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, syslog

A service failed on my server with this message:
`systemd[1]: my.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=24/XCPU`

What does it mean? I couldn't find anything related to this status.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64. OpenVZ container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service was killed for using too much CPU time.

From `man 7 signal`:

> SIGXCPU 24,24,30    Core    CPU time limit exceeded (4.2BSD);

This is specific to OpenVZ where the provider can impose resource limits.