# systemd DefaultLimitCPUSoft?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ulimit

I discovered that on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS a process is getting killed due to CPU usage.

Running `ulimit -t` shows 86400.

`systemctl show | grep LimitCPU` shows

```
DefaultLimitCPU=18446744073709551615
DefaultLimitCPUSoft=86400
```

I talked to the provider support and they said they don't set any limits for the OpenVZ container.

I looked in */etc/systemd/system.conf* and */etc/systemd/user.conf* but I didn't find anything.

Any idea where this limit could be set? It's driving me mad, especially since I didn't add this limit and I have another VPS with same software & settings that doesn't have this limit.

Comment: What is the proof, that the process gets killed due to CPU usage? As a workaround you could renice the process or split the work in two if possible.

Comment: I saw in syslog `systemd[1]: my.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=24/XCPU`
The process needs to run uninterrupted and with normal priority.

Comment: ah, I see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/888289/what-is-status-24-xpu-in-syslog

Comment: Your VPS provider probably doesn't know what they're doing. This is just one more reason to avoid OpenVZ.

Comment: Possible, but I have another OpenVZ container, with the same provider, same Ubuntu version, pretty much the same software installed, just on a different datacenter, that does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is here: https://openvz.org/Resource_shortage

Check if you have failcnt > 0 if you do this:

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters
```

Comment: Nope, failcnt is 0 for all items.